# WCF service leaks handles and memory when a client times out

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I've got a net.tcp WCF service running in a self-hosted environment.  I've setup a forced scenario where the server will run a method of the service for long enough that the client time's out. I.e:

```
[OperationContract]
public bool someMethod() {
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
    return true;
}
```

On the client:

```
public void callSomeMethod() {
     using (var proxy = getProxy()) {
         proxy.someMethod();
     }
}
```

When the client times out after 60 seconds, one or more handles are leaked on the server. Doing this repeatedly will eventually lead to a server crash because it's out of resources.

Note: On the client, I intentionally am not cleaning up by using Close()/Abort() for this test. My theory is that if the client ever connects to the server but is interrupted before the connection can be cleaned up, the server will leak.

One final word- when I look at ProcessExplorer, it's showing that my leaks are TCP sockets.

Is there a better way to handle this server-side? I've seen references to using a ChannelFactory, but I'm not sure on the details (is that even server-side code?) If so, would it give me any more control over making sure error states get cleaned up properly?

**EDIT**

I've since done some searching on ChannelFactory and I see it's a client-side feature, not server side, so disregard that. Still open though about if there's a way to more properly clean up leaked ports.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory & Handle Leaks in my ServiceHost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613752/memory-handle-leaks-in-my-servicehost)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I was running my service from a [STAThread] - anytime an app uses COM calls, you'll potentially leak memory unless you are running [MTAThread] mode.