# Memory leak in WCF (Duplex) on Server

Tags: wcf, memory-leaks, duplex

Hi have quite a problem with an Service running WCF in duplex-mode.
It leaks memory (not much but it's about 80MB a day) and after having a memory-profiler running alongside the service for 24 hours I found most of the memory sitting in `byte[]` referenced by quite a mess but I most references end in something like this:
[image: one path holding the byte[] - array] 
and the "root" looks like this:
[image: root]

I too see lots of `ServiceChannel` (around 200) comming (I think) from the callback-channels.

I'm rather sure that I only hold 1 of those for each of the connected clients.

Overall my problem seems to be almost the same as this: [memory leak in silverlight Wcf implementation](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/73436.aspx/3/10) but on the server-side.

I even tried the `[MTAThread]` thing mentioned here: [WCF service leaks handles and memory when a client times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654627/wcf-service-leaks-handles-and-memory-when-a-client-times-out) but it just don't solve the problem.

I just don't think that the problem is with my code as I wrap the callback-channels after getting it with `OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServiceConnectorCallback>()` in one of my own objects and those don't leak (there is only one of those for each clients in memory at any given snapshot) - sure I reset those callbacks on several occasions as the channel might change (clients losing the connection or reconnecting) but I don't have a way of disposing the old references so I only drop them and the GC should do it's job on them.

I do use `PerCall` on my service so I don't have any handle to those objects in my code at all.

I really have no clue at how I can handle this aside from restarting the service every few days - a solution I don't want to probose right now :(

So please give me some help/hints on this - thank you very much!

Comment: Do you see a higher memory gain if the clients fault alot and you have to recreate the callback channel? Do you `Abort` the callback channel if the client has gone away?

Comment: It's hard for me to tell but this might be the case - and no I don't abort the channel on the server (how can I do this - using `GetCallbackChannel<T>` I only get `T` - do you have to cast this into some kind of proxy?)

Comment: You should be able to cast it to `IClientChannel`

Comment: thank you - found this on another post and am implementing this right now. When I get you right, I should call .`Abort` on the Clientchannel if the Faulted-Event is raised right? - I think I can even improve on my code by handling the .Close as well so I don't have run into trouble by posting to a disconnected client anymore.

Comment: am testing this right now - I think I have to wait some hours to see if this is ok - BTW: should I call dispose on closed/faulted `IClientChanels`?

Comment: what I can tell already is that there ARE a lot of faulted-callback channels - I guess this is because the clients are moving around and chaning accesspoints quite a bit

Comment: I'm using a NetTcpBinding for this

Comment: Sadly it seems like this does not fix the problem - maybe I should try to Dispose the Clientchannels?

Comment: `Dispose` on the channel simply calls `Close` - you still need to Abort a faulted channel. Are you storing the client channel and retrieving it from the `OperationContext` every time? if so you should `Close` it when you're finished with it after each time you use it

Comment: yes I learned the hard way that Dispose is not a good idea - and yes I'm retrieving/setting the channel on every call I get from each client so I can update them on demand. But as far as I can tell the channel will be the same on every call so I only replace them if not so - I don't close the channel in this case right now as the old channel should have been faulted/closed anyhow but I guess I could try to add a guarded (only on State=Opened) call to close there if you think this is the way to go

Comment: @Richard: please post your comment in answer form - seems like this solves the problem (Abort each Clientchannel if a new one is registered) or at least the majority of it - thank you very much!

Comment: @CarstenKönig what memory analyzer do you use ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland I don't need them very often but I did buy a licence for the ANTS MemoryProfiler from RedGate - but most I did look at back than had a trial version and I would recommend trying those and decide for yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a session based channel faults a call to `Close` will throw an exception. However, there are proxy side resources that are not cleaned up in this case and these are only cleaned up when you `Abort` the faulted channel

Make sure that when you replace a faulted channel that you `Abort` the old one first